# Its a simple loop but I do not know how to do it

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I need to parse the following xml but when I use my code it just read the first p tags, I know its a simple loop but I am confused.

```
 <s>
 <j u="here1"/>
   <p v="here1_1"/>
   <p v="here1_2"/>
   <p v="here1_3"/>
   <p v="here1_4"/>
   <p v="here1_5"/>
   <p v="here1_6"/>
</s>
<s>
 <j u="here2" />
   <p v="here2_1"/>
   <p v="here2_2"/>
   <p v="here2_3"/>
   <p v="here2_4"/>
   <p v="here2_5"/>
   <p v="here2_6"/>
</s>
```

mycode

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($myXml);
foreach ($xml->s as $tags) {
        echo $tags->j->attributes()->u . " ";
        echo $tags->p->attributes()->v . " ";
    }
```

result is >>> here1 here1_1 here2 here2_1

but the result should be here1 here1_1 ..... here1_6 here2 here2_1 ..... here2_6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since there are multiple p tags you need to loop through p tags

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($myXml);
foreach ($xml->s as $tags) {
        echo $tags->j->attributes()->u . " ";
        foreach($tags->p as $ptags){
            echo $ptags->attributes()->v . " ";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($myXml);
foreach ($xml->s as $tags) foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->attributes()->u . " "; // $tag['u'] you can access attributes like this too
    echo $tag->attributes()->v . " "; // $tag['v']
}
```

This should give you

```
here1
here1_1 
here1_2 
here1_3 
here1_4 
here1_5 
here1_6 
here2 
here2_1 
here2_2 
here2_3 
here2_4 
here2_5 
here2_6
```